# How to prevent newtx from changing footnotemark style?

Tags: newtx

I am using LuaTex with newtx package. However, using newtx changes the style of the \footnotemark command. However, I want the original style of \footnotemark in the superscript without the square brackets. How can I get back the default style?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test title}
  Test text.\footnotemark[1]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

MWE without newtx package:
[image: MWE without newtx package]

MWE with newtx package:
[image: MWE with newtx package]

Comment: well newtxtext contains `\renewcommand{\footnotemark}{\normalfont}` and that is a clear bug. Write to the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: The issue should've been fixed with v1.73 2023-10-29

Something is very fishy. When Unicode engines are used (and no KOMA class), then `newtxtext` does

```
% newtxtext.sty l. 507
\renewcommand{\footnotemark}{\normalfont}
```

which is definitely a bug. Not sure what it should've been, but a workaround would be

```
\let\originalfootnotemark\footnotemark
\usepackage{newtx}
\let\footnotemark\originalfootnotemark
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are anyway compiling with lualatex and the `fontspec` package, you could directly use a font of your choice:

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

%\usepackage{newtx}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test title}
  Test text.\footnotemark[1]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually `newtx` does load `fontspec` and uses basically TeX Gyre Termes. But the bit with `\footnotemark` looks really like a serious bug in `newtx`.

Comment: @campa Thanks for your comment! I'll update to TeX Gyre Termes, Times New Roman was close but the spacing was a bit different

Comment: Can't upvote again. But the issue is a serious bug in `newtx`, I've already informed the author. (And also sorry again for the noise on GitHub: that's was my first try raising an issue... `:-)`)

Comment: @campa No worries about noise. I totally understand the irritation about the warning, the duplicate issue I linked you to was created with my old github account :)

Comment: @campa Just curious: why did you delete your answer? It seems to work fine.

Comment: Erm, because when I was done writing it I noticed Ulrike's comment and I didn't know whether she was going to answer too. I pinged her and if she doesn't react I'll undelete.

Comment: @campa Ah, makes sense. I'll keep this tab open in case I get a chance to upvote your answer :P